# Ошибка с выводом текста на готовую картинку php

Tags: php

Друзья, смотрела темы похожие, но ответа не нашла.
Где тут косяк, подскажите, пожалуйста. Текст не выводит.

```
$text= $_POST["myName"].$score;
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('CertificateBackgrounds3.jpg');
$x=500;
$y=600;
$TextColor  = ImageColorAllocate($img, 777, 777, 777); 
$font = 'src/roboto.ttf';
imagettftext ($img, 30, 0, 55, 50, $x, $y, $TextColor, $font, $text);
header( 'Content-type: image/png' );
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: А что у Вас за конструкция такая интересная $text= $_POST["myName"].$score ? И если она валидная, то что после неё в переменной $text?

Comment: Вы $text проверяете?

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис я только учусь) if (isset($_POST['check'])) { $score = array_sum($_POST); $text= 'Поздравляем, ' . $_POST["myName"].'! Вы заработали '.$score.' баллов!';

Comment: И что после этого выводит var_dump($text); ?

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис string(43) "Поздравляем, name! Вы заработали 1 баллов!"

Answer (score 0):

Этот код рабочий, есть одна ошибка в imagettftext.
И цвет Что за цвет RGB 777 777 777? Каждое число должно быть от 0 до 255.
Для проверки я поставил 100,100,100 Выберите сами. В поиске например "html цвета" получите страницы с таблицами, выберите оттуда нужный цвет.

```
$text= $_POST["myName"].$score;
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('CertificateBackgrounds3.jpg');
$x=500;
$y=600;
$TextColor  = ImageColorAllocate($img, 100, 100, 100); 
$font = 'src/roboto.ttf';
imagettftext ($img, 30, 0, $x, $y, $TextColor, $font, $text);
header( 'Content-type: image/png' );
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Чтобы проверить грузится ли изображение или есть ли текст нужно закомментировать строку с header.
 Проверить загрузку изображения можно так:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('CertificateBackgrounds3.jpg');
if ($img){
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

Проверить текcт можно через echo. Но header должен быть закомментирован, чтобы это увидеть.

И еще один важный момент - должна быть подключена библиотека GD. Это можно проверить через phpinfo();

Comment: большое спасибо! увлеклась) вообще 777777 - серый, но не rgb, да) проверила - текст есть, GD подключена. но на картинке его нет(

Comment: попробуйте изменить координаты $x и $y - может они находятся за пределами изображения. например 50 и 60. для теста

Comment: Еще можно попробовать $font прописать так: $font = realpath('src/roboto.ttf'); Может шрифт не находит.